# Conditional else/if operator to perform different functions

Tags: python, modifiers

When the object is in edit mode, I want to execute this:-

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF")
```

And if the same object is in object mode, I want to execute this instead:-

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLDIFY')
```

I'm really confused about setting up the conditional operators regarding to the context of the object(modes). How do i it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this in the context.

```
mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode
if mode == 'EDIT':
    ...

elif mode == 'OBJECT':
    ...
```